# What תוֹרָ֔ה is referred to in Isaiah 2:3?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-study, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

[Isaiah 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.2.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> Many peoples shall come and say, “Come, let us go up to the mountain of
> the Lord,
> to the house of the God of Jacob; that he may teach us his ways and that we may walk in his paths.” For out of Zion shall go forth
> **instruction**, and the word of the Lord from Jerusalem.

What law/instruction is referred to in the verse?

Is it necessarily the blessed Torah God inspired to Moses?

Comment: Cf https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3885

Comment: Also Michah 4:2

Answer (score 4):

This verse is based on a few verses in the [Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.9?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&ven=Metsudah_Chumash,_Metsudah_Publications,_2009_%5Bwith_Onkelos_translation%5D&lang=en&with=Commentary&lang2=he)

> If a matter of law is too abstruse for you—between blood and blood, between decision and decision, or between leprosy [a plague of confinement] and leprosy [a plague of confinement], matters under [legal] dispute in your city; you shall rise and ascend to the place that Adonoy, your God, will have chosen.
> You are to come before the kohanim-the Levites and the judge officiating during those days; you will inquire and they will tell you the legal decision.
> You are to act according to the word that they tell you from that place that Adonoy will have chosen; and you are to be careful to fulfill exactly as they instruct you.
> In accord with the Torah that they instruct you and upon the law that they state to you, are you to act; do not deviate from the word they tell you, neither right or left.

that command Jews to go to the place G-d will choose (Jerusalem) to listen to the rulings of the High Court. Isaiah prophesizes that in the future, all nations will recognize the truth of the Torah, and will go to learn it from its highest authority.

Answer (score 1):

The *law* referred to is those laws which apply to the descendants of Noach. These laws were also restated at the giving of the Torah at Sinai.

Proper understanding of what those laws are and how every individual can best  cleave to the Creator of us all is transmitted to the nations by Israel.

This is in keeping with the idea of being a light to the nations.

And this is the very essence of the second paragraph of the Aleinu prayer said at the close of each of the daily prayer services which is attributed to Yehoshuah (Joshua).

> We therefore put our hope in You, L-rd our G-d, to soon behold the glory of Your might in banishing idolatry from the earth, and the false gods will be utterly exterminated to perfect the world as the kingdom of Shadai. And all mankind will invoke Your Name, to return to You, all the wicked of the earth. They will realize and know, all the inhabitants of the world, that to You, every knee must bend, every tongue must swear *[allegiance to You]*. Before You, L-rd, our G-d, they will bow and prostrate themselves, and to the glory of Your Name give honor. And they will all accept *[upon themselves]* the yoke of Your Kingship, and You will reign over them, soon, forever and ever. For the Kingship is Yours, and to all eternity You will reign in glory, as it is written in Your Torah: *the* L-rd will reign forever and ever. And it is said: And *the* L-rd will be King over the whole earth; on that day  *the* L-rd will be One and His Name One.

That we look with hope to You, L-rd, our G-d, to soon see, through the *culmination of Torah study and prayer* (בתפארת), Your brilliance (עזך); to remove *the confusion of inappropriate adulation* (גלולים) from the earth. And those *heroes/icons* (והאלילים) will be absolutely divested. To harmonize the world (לתקן עולם) in relation to *the paramount priority of the continuation and propagation of life* (במלכות שדי).